# Can I load objects to unity dynamically?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im quite new to unity. I need to load the objects ( car models ) into a car game. What i want is to read the car models from a folder and load them dynamically. When i add new items later into some folder or web directory it should show in the unity game.

is this possible to do?

Comment: A brief search tells me that you can. This should be helpful: [link 1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7653/dynamic-asset-loading.html) [Link 2](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/41899-Need-help-for-dynamic-loading-of-outer-models...) [from Unity3d's documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Loading%20Resources%20at%20Runtime.html)